# When is Memcached required?

Tags: memcached, scalability

I'm building a site that I hope will achieve the same sort of traffic as SO.

I know early optimisation is the root of all evil and all but I keep telling myself that I have to have a caching strategy baked into the design.

I'm using the LAMP stack and to begin with I'll be doing everything on one dedicated server.

Do you think it's not worth the effort to incorporate Memecahced into the project from day one?

Thanks

Comment: Deciding on your architecture is not the same thing as 'early optimization'. You *must* do one, you should generally try to avoid the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definetely worth the effort!

Once your website starts scaling really fast, it will be very hard for you to only then start taking care of all the big scalability problems.

...Besides, Memcached is very easy to implement!

:)

Comment: Any gotchas I should look out for when implementing memcached?

Comment: What language/framework are you using for your site ? I used memcached with .net a couple of times, so I used the Enyim extension for memchached. With Enyim, it takes care of almost everything for you, and as long as the configuration is right (web server names and addresses) then all you do is use the memcached like regular asp.net server cache, so implementing for me was VERY easy and intuitive. Good Luck! :)